# Can the bounds for the number of Carmichael numbers below $x$ be made more concrete?

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

On the page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number

at the part "*distribution*", lower and upper bounds for the number of Carmichael numbers below $x$ (denoted by $C(x)$) are given. Two questions about these bounds :

> Which constant can be used for the upper bound ? Does $k_2=1$ do the job ?
>
> What does "sufficiently large" mean for the lower bound ? For which $x$ does $\large C(x)>x^\frac{2}{7}$ hold ?